# Can't access static resources with Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

According to the Spring Boot documentation, resources located in the `static` folder will be served up automatically by Spring Boot with no additional configuration or request mapping.

I am trying to access a javascript file by going to **`http://localhost:8080/js/filter.js`**

---

Here is a screenshot of that section of that part of the **Spring documentation.**

[image: spring documentation screenshot]

---

Here is a screenshot of my current **`resources` directory structure**.

[image: directory structure]

---

Here is my **`pom.xml`** to show that I'm using the latest Spring Boot release.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>velocity-demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>velocity-demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.2.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.velocity</groupId>
            <artifactId>velocity</artifactId>
            <version>1.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.gson/gson -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

---

Here is my **Application class**

```
package com.example

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class VelocityDemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(VelocityDemoApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Comment: What you show  seems fine. The problem is probably caused by something in your Spring configuration. Can you show all of it ?

Comment: There is no further configuration. I'll add my Application class to the post, but it's the vanilla class.

Comment: Indeed. It is rather simple. But is it **all** ? I have just tested and it works.

Comment: Solved. It was because I had a `@PostMapping` in my controller without specifying the value. Changed it to `@PostMapping("/foo")` and I can access everything now.

Comment: you didn't mention any controller at all in the question, so I'm not sure how this would solve anything for anybody else - so voting to close

Comment: I never thought to look at the controller because it wasn't apparent at all that it could be an issue with the controller. I definitely could see someone else having this same issue and not thinking to look at their controller.

Answer (score 0):

In my controller I changed `@PostMapping` to `@PostMapping("/foo")` and now I can get all of my resources. It was essentially blocking all my requests.

I'll leave this question up, unless of course it gets deleted, because I never would have thought that the controller being configured that way would be blocking all other requests. Someone else may have this issue one day.

```
@RestController
public class MainController {

    TemplateService templateService;

    public MainController(TemplateService templateService) {
        this.templateService = templateService;
    }

    @GetMapping("/")
    public String getIndex() {
        return templateService.getTemplate("index.vm");
    }

    @PostMapping("/updateFilter") // was @PostMapping
    public String updateFilter() {
        System.out.println("updating filter");
        return "success";
    }
}
```